# insert a json file into json

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'd like to know a quick way to insert a json to json.

```
$ cat source.json

{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "SERVICE_MANIFEST",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "SERVICE_PORT",
          "value": "4321"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The SERVICE_MANIFEST is content of another json file

```
$ cat service_manifest.json

{
  "connections": {
    "port": "1234"
  },
  "name": "foo"
}
```

I try to make it with jq command

```
cat service_manifest.json |jq --arg SERVICE_MANIFEST - < source.json
```

But seems it doesn't work

Any ideas? The final result still should be a valid json file

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "SERVICE_MANIFEST",
          "value": {
            "connections": {
              "port": "1234"
            },
            "name": "foo"
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

#### Updates.

Thanks, here is the command I run from your sample.

> $ jq --slurpfile sm service_manifest.json '.containerDefinitions[].environment[] |= (select(.name=="SERVICE_MANIFEST").value=$sm)' source.json

But the result is an array, not list.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "SERVICE_MANIFEST",
          "value": [
            {
              "connections": {
                "port": "1234"
              },
              "name": "foo"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "SERVICE_PORT",
          "value": "4321"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Replace the `...` and provide actual JSON content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `jq` command:

```
jq --slurpfile sm SERVICE_MANIFEST '.containerDefinitions[].environment[] |= (select(.name=="SERVICE_MANIFEST").value=$sm[])' file
```

`--slurpfile` assigns the content of the file to the variable `sm`

The filter replaces the array `.containerDefinitions[].environment[]` with the content of the file only on the element having `SERVICE_MANIFEST` as `name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the value become an array, not list, that's not my expect result.

Comment: Here is the command I run for your reference : `jq --slurpfile sm service_manifest.json '.containerDefinitions[].environment[] |= (select(.name=="SERVICE_MANIFEST").value=$sm)' source.json
`

Comment: Note the `[]` sign after the `$sm` at the end of the filter in my answer. This will remove the array for the `value` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would use `--argfile` and avoid `select`:

```
< source.json jq --argfile sm service_manifest.json '
  .containerDefinitions[0].environment[0].value = $sm '
```

Or if you want only to update the object(s) with `.name == "SERVICE_MANIFEST"` you could use the filter:

```
.containerDefinitions[].environment 
  |= map(if .name == "SERVICE_MANIFEST"
         then .value = $sm 
         else . end)
```

### Variations

There is no need for any "--arg"-style parameter at all, as illustrated by the following:

```
jq -s '.[1] as $sm
  | .[0] | .containerDefinitions[0].environment[0].value = $sm
' source.json service_manifest.json
```

Comment: Thanks, looks neat solution. But the environment variables are not always the same sequence, `environment[0]` is not suitable in this case.

Comment: But I worked it out with your way: `jq --argfile sm service_manifest.json '.containerDefinitions[].environment[] |= (select(.name=="SERVICE_MANIFEST").value=$sm)' source.json`